# React-router: Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm following [React Router Guide](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/README.md) but I'm not even getting to make the simplest example to work. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined`.

I'm including these 3 JavaScript files through `cdnjs`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.12.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/0.11.6/react-router.js"></script>
```

And the script the triggers the exception is this:

```
<script type="text/jsx">
    Router.run(routes, function (Handler, state) {
        React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
    });
</script>
```

Am I missing anything? Is `Router` defined somewhere else? That's weird because it's not stated in the docs.

Comment: The link is broken. Working is [React Router Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/master/docs/guides)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

react-router is defined as ReactRouter on global.

You can access like this.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
ReactRouter.run(routes, function (Handler, state) {
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate that. It works. I think the documentation must be updated then. But now I get `Route` is not defined. Any idea?

Comment: You can find in `ReactRouter.Route`.

Comment: @thanks... I'm using the `cdnjs` so I guess these exports aren't available.

Comment: Doesn't it still work? I'm using the `cdnjs` too. http://jsfiddle.net/koba04/j55r60m1/1/

Comment: Oh no. It's working. I just said the exports are not available in the sense that `Route`, as stated in the documentation, is not available. You have to  use `ReactRouter.Route`. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69166/discussion-between-koba04-and-andre-pena).